# Simple question on factoring the difference of 2 perfect squares

Tags: factoring

> (b) (i) Use the identity $A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$ to factorise the expression $5^{2k}-1$.

Do I just put the k as 1 so that the equation is 5^2 and 1^2

Thanks

Steve

Comment: No, there is no reason to think $k=1$.

Comment: You can think of $5^{2k}$ as $(5^k)^2$

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the help so would the factor be simply (5^k-1)(5^k+1)

Answer (score 1):

For all real numbers A and B,
$$A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$$
Substituting $$A=5^k$$ and $$B=1$$,
$$(5^k)^2-1^2=(5^k-1)(5^k+1)
\implies 5^{2k}-1= (5^k-1)(5^k+1)$$
Note that 5^k-1 can be further factorised if k is a natural number.
In that case,
$$5^k-1=(5-1)(1+5^1+5^2+5^3+......+5^{k-1}) = 4*(1+5^1+5^2+5^3+......+5^{k-1})$$

Comment: @Steve If you are satisfied by the answer, you may consider accepting it.